# Why I can't unpack the parameters for sklearn model using clf(**params)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am just trying to to write a class to help me create object. Each object is a machine learning model (ex: XGBoostRegressor, RandomForestRegressor, ...) However, when I use (**params), there is an error that 'RandomForestRegressor' object is not callable

I have tried looking it up but seems like it is a me problem ):

```
class SklearnExtra(object):
    def __init__(self, clf, seed = 0, params = None):
        params['random_state'] = seed
        self.clf = clf(**params)

    def train(self, x, y):
        self.clf.fit(x, y)

    def predict(self, x):
        return self.clf.predict(x)

    def fit(self, x, y):
        return self.clf.fit(x,y)

    def feature_importances(self, x, y):
        clf2 = self.clf.fit(x,y)
        return (clf2.feature_importances_)
```

```
rf_params = {'n_estimators': 1000, 'n_jobs': -1, 'warm_start': True, 'max_features':2}
Seed = 26121997
rf = SklearnExtra(clf = RandomForestRegressor(), seed = Seed, params = rf_params)
```

the error says 'RandomForestRegressor' object is not callable

Comment: Hey, could you please post your whole `traceback`? It's easier to debug that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clf = RandomForestRegressor()` assigns `clf` to an instance of the class `RandomForestRegressor` instead of assigning it to the class itself.
The program then fails on `self.clf = clf(**params)` because you are trying to instantiate and object from the instance, which is not possible.

In order to fix the problem, just pass the `RandomForestRegressor` class to the `clf` parameter without the brackets:

```
rf = SklearnExtra(clf = RandomForestRegressor, seed = Seed, params = rf_params)
```